# sketching path on unit simplex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to simulate a path on the unit simplex, which can be drawn using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \def\laxis{5}
  \def\ltriangle{3}
  \begin{scope}[->,red]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (\laxis,0,0) node [below] {\textcolor{blue}{$x$}};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,\laxis,0) node [right] {\textcolor{blue}{$y$}};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\laxis) node [left] {\textcolor{blue}{$z$}};
  \end{scope}
  \filldraw [opacity=.5,green] (\ltriangle,0,0) -- (0,\ltriangle,0) --
  (0,0,\ltriangle) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've sketched an outline:

[image]

Where the corners are the coordinates (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1).The page is just a random set of coordinates such that the elements add up to 1, and I want to feed the coordinates into the program to sketch the path over the simplex, im not really sure how I can do this though.

Example of a path for 6 time steps:

```
(0.25,0.5,0.25) , (0.2,0.6,0.2), (0.24,0.56,0.2), (0.16,0.52,0.0.32),(0.12,0.5,0.38), (0.1,0.46,0.44)
```

Comment: Do you have the coordinates for the paths? If so, could you please add them to your question?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina added a short path example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  view/h=134.5,
  axis lines=center,
  xmax=1.5, 
  ymax=1.5,
  zmax=1.5,
  ytick={1},
  xlabel={$X_{1}$},
  ylabel={$X_{2}$},
  zlabel={$X_{3}$},
]
\addplot3[patch,green!70!black!50,forget plot] 
  coordinates 
  {
  (1,0,0) 
  (0,1,0) 
  (0,0,1)
  };
\addplot3[no markers,red!90!black] 
  coordinates 
  { 
  (0.25,0.1,0.45) 
  (0.2,0.1,0.4) 
  (0.24,0.36,0.4) 
  (0.16,0.32,0.62) 
  (0.12,0.3,0.58) 
  (0.1,0.26,0.64) 
  };
\addplot3[no markers,blue] 
  coordinates 
  { 
  (0.25,0.5,0.25) 
  (0.2,0.6,0.2) 
  (0.24,0.56,0.2) 
  (0.16,0.52,0.32) 
  (0.12,0.5,0.38) 
  (0.1,0.46,0.44) 
  };
\legend{$Y$,$Z$};
\node[fill=blue,inner sep=1pt,circle,label={180:$Z$}] 
  at (axis cs:0.25,0.5,0.25) {};  
\node[fill=red!90!black,inner sep=1pt,circle,label={180:$Y$}] 
  at (axis cs:0.1,0.26,0.64) {};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to center the triangle a bit more and hide the aces as I had it in my sketch on paper?

Comment: also i keep getting an error about the compat=1.12 and the image comes up quite weird when i run the code.. I've tried updating my version of pgf plots but still not working

Comment: @dimebucker91 You're welcome! Please see my updated answer. Use `compat=newest` so `pgfplots` will use the most updated version in your system (I did some tests with older versions and it should work from version 1.8 on).